Client socket exception error on android9 pie devices using usb debugging how to setup ipaddress for that
import 'dart:io';

class ServerConstant {
static String serverURL =
Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:8000' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
}

//These code clientSocketException connection refused error using usb cable for debugging suggested how to resolve this issue
